# Simple circuit to light a LED only if I have a square wave

Tags: led, square

I have a simple circuit with a transistor that accepts an input 3.3V square wave (50Hz) and amplifies it to a 20V output inverted square wave.
I'd like to have a LED that lights up if the square wave is active and goes off if no input signal.
If I just put a LED on the output it doesn't work, it lights up when no signal and it lights slightly dimmed when the square wave is active.
Is it possible to achieve this in a simple way?
EDIT:
The circuit power supply is 24V, the input square wave is 3.3V

Comment: 20V pulse is used for what? WHat if Clock runs But pulse fails for some reason?

Comment: Apparently, the square wave is zero when "inactive". When you invert it, the LED is constantly driven.

Comment: Yes, as I use a single transistor, the output is active when input is 0V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit below could be considered to be a monostable multivibrator, as Spehro suggested, but is cruder than most such circuits. Using an IC will give a "clean" result more easily, but this can be made to work well with suitable design and/or playing.
**Component values shown are examples only !!!**

This would work on input or output with suitable component values.
Loading of the waveform by C1 may need to be considered depending on the nature of the source.

A MOSFET could be used for Q1. On the input side an "on voltage" (Vgsth) lowe enough to accomodate the 3V3 swing would be needed. On the output side allowance for the high voltage would be needed as most MOSFETS are better operated with lower gate-source voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnGvWk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

One gate of a hex Schmitt inverter (eg 74HC14) could be used in place of the transistor - leaving the other 5 inverters for "playing". You could eg have an LED that flashed at a steady rate regardless of input frequency, flashed only initially then steadied, or vice versa or .... . 
The amount of useful, and fun, things that can be done with a package of hex Schmitt inverters is astounding.

**Just for fun - or usefulness**

Gate 1 serves the same function as the above transistor circuit.
Gate two provides a flashing LED at a user defined frequency when the square wave is present.  4 square gates invite experiment.

The LED drive is limited by the gate drive capabilty. For brighter LEDs a transistor buffer can be added. Component values are "indicative".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frbBbT.png)</sup>

Comment: Nice! I'm amazed no one proposed a NE555 ;-)

Comment: @PedroNF I've spent half a long lifetime trying to stop people using xx555s. The 74C14 does about as much and with many more gates when you need the extra features.  || Bonus: Bias Vin at half supply and AC couple in AC and you get an audio amp! :-) - PWM filterable to AC. Gain can be adjusted, sort of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, look at using a retriggerable monostable multivibrator to turn the 3.3V square wave into a sustained 3.3V logic level. You set the timing to be longer than the period of the square wave.

For example, [74HC123](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc123.pdf).

You could also do it with a charge pump (capacitors, diodes) and a transistor + resistor but I think the above method is more elegant and  uses fewer components.

Comment: That's the way I used to do it 40 years ago. (Before HC existed, so I was using LS.) Last time I looked for the LS variety it seemed expensive. But these HC types seem pretty cheap, now that I'm looking at them. I think it's the better solution, too.

Comment: The 74HC123 looks like a good option. The 3.3V signal comes from another device, in this circuit I only have a BJT and some resistors, powered by 24V (only have 24V available), the BJT converts the 3.3V square wave into a higher voltage square wave that is sent to another device (opto coupler) that is a few meters away.

Comment: By the way, I'm surprised that no one suggested a circuit based on the NE555 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what supply voltage you have available, which complicates things.

Let's say you have 5 volts. Then

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMpD0p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 form a 4:1 voltage divider which will reduce the input to a 5-volt square wave and will not overdrive the 74HC04 which is supplied by 5 volts. The 74HC04 will invert the square wave so that the inactive level is 0 volts and the LED is off. R3 will depend somewhat on the color of the LED - it will provide 2-3 mA for a red LED, and much less for white. Don't reduce R3 too much, since the 74HC04 can't supply more than a few mA.

Or, you can use a transistor as an inverter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftbZE3.png)</sup>

In this case, set R2 to V1/10 in kohm/volt. That is, if V1 is 10 volts, use 1k for R2. For larger voltages, say 10 to 20 volts, this will give about 10 mA through the LED regardless of color.

Regardless of color, the LED will noticeably flicker - this is because it is pulsing at 20 Hz, well below the frequency at which the eye smooths things out.

Comment: "Lets say you have 5 Volts." Shouldn't it be 20 volts? Also why 20 Hz, isn't it specified as 50 in the question? I also did not understand the inverting action of q1 in the second picture.

Comment: I edited the question to add the power voltage, its powered by 24V.

Comment: I decided that though it says "no signal" there is too much chance that this ends up meaning eg "floats high when off" - so used AC couple versions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the LED powered from the 3.3V incoming signal? LED/series resistor between Base or Gate and Gnd. Can the 3.3V source spare a couple of mA to drive an LED?

Comment: The objective is twofold, quick check that we have a square wave and that the output is working. If I do it on the input it doesn't tell me the output BJT is ok and running.

Comment: Then put it on the output. (24V - 2.2V)/.01A = 2.2k.  Will be quite bright when not working, and appear dimmer when it is working.